# Hyperledger Docker Container Dependency

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been developing some Hyperledger networks with Hyperledger Composer and I have a question around the Docker containers which are created. Every time I make an update I have to "Deploy changes" which spins up a new Docker container so I have a huge list of Docker containers. I was wondering if the new deployment containers are dependent on the previous ones or can I `docker rm` them?

[image: List of Docker Containers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They Are independent , you can remove the old container as long as you don't use the old container that contains old smart contract.